# Fixing variance values in lme4

Tags: r, lme4

I am using the `lme4` R package to create a linear mixed model using the `lmer()` function. In this model I have four random effects and one fixed effect (intercept). My question is about the estimated variances of the random effects. Is it possible to specify initial values for the covariance parameters in a similar way as it can be done in `SAS` with the `PARMS` argument.

In the following example, the estimated variances are:

```
c(0.00000, 0.03716, 0.00000, 0.02306)
```

I would like to *fix* these to (for example)

```
c(0.09902947, 0.02460464, 0.05848691, 0.06093686)
```

so there are not estimated.

```
    > summary(mod1)
    Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
    Formula: log_cumcover_mod ~ (1 | kildestationsnavn) + (1 | year) + (1 |  
        kildestationsnavn:year) + (1 | proevetager)
       Data: res

         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
       109.9    122.9    -48.9     97.9       59 

    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -2.1056 -0.6831  0.2094  0.8204  1.7574 

    Random effects:
     Groups                 Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     kildestationsnavn:year (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
     kildestationsnavn      (Intercept) 0.03716  0.1928  
     proevetager            (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
     year                   (Intercept) 0.02306  0.1518  
     Residual                           0.23975  0.4896  
    Number of obs: 65, groups:  
    kildestationsnavn:year, 6; kildestationsnavn, 3; proevetager, 2; year, 2

    Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error t value
    (Intercept)   4.9379     0.1672   29.54
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix"? Can you describe this in your question? Links to off-site resources may go offline without notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible, if a little hacky. Here's a reproducible example:

Fit the original model:

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
ss <- sleepstudy[sample(nrow(sleepstudy),size=round(0.9*nrow(sleepstudy))),]
m1 <- lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject)+(0+Days|Subject),ss)
fixef(m1)
## (Intercept)        Days 
##   251.55172    10.37874
```

Recover the deviance (in this case REML-criterion) function:

```
dd <- as.function(m1)
```

I'm going to set the standard deviations to zero so that I have something to compare with, i.e. the coefficients of the regular linear model. (The parameter vector for `dd` is a vector containing the column-wise, lower-triangular, concatenated Cholesky factors for the *scaled* random effects terms in the model.  Luckily, if all you have are scalar/intercept-only random effects (e.g. `(1|x)`), then these correspond to the random-effects standard deviations, *scaled by the model standard deviation*).

```
(ff <- dd(c(0,0)))  ## new REML: 1704.708
environment(dd)$pp$beta(1)  ## new parameters
##    [1] 251.11920  10.56979
```

Matches:

```
coef(lm(Reaction~Days,ss))
## (Intercept)        Days 
##   251.11920    10.56979
```

If you want to construct a new `merMod` object you can do it as follows ...

```
opt <- list(par=c(0,0),fval=ff,conv=0)
lmod <- lFormula(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject)+(0+Days|Subject),ss)
m1X <- mkMerMod(environment(dd), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr,
         mc = quote(hacked_lmer()))
```

Now suppose we want to set the variances to particular non-zero value (say (700,30)).  This will be a little bit tricky because of the scaling by the residual standard deviation ...

```
newvar <- c(700,30)
ff2 <- dd(sqrt(newvar)/sigma(m1))
opt2 <- list(par=c(0,0),fval=ff,conv=0)
m2X <- mkMerMod(environment(dd), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr,
         mc = quote(hacked_lmer()))
VarCorr(m2X)
unlist(VarCorr(m2X))
##   Subject Subject.1 
## 710.89304  30.46684
```

So this doesn't get us quite where we wanted (because the residual variance changes ...)

```
buildMM <- function(theta) {
   dd <- as.function(m1)
   ff <- dd(theta)
   opt <- list(par=c(0,0),fval=ff,conv=0)
   mm <- mkMerMod(environment(dd), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr,
         mc = quote(hacked_lmer()))
   return(mm)
}

objfun <- function(x,target=c(700,30)) {
   mm <- buildMM(sqrt(x))
   return(sum((unlist(VarCorr(mm))-target)^2))
}
s0 <- c(700,30)/sigma(m1)^2
opt <- optim(fn=objfun,par=s0)
mm_final <- buildMM(sqrt(opt$par))
summary(mm_final)
##  Random effects:
##  Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  Subject   (Intercept) 700      26.458  
##  Subject.1 Days         30       5.477  
##  Residual              700      26.458  
## Number of obs: 162, groups:  Subject, 18
## 
## Fixed effects:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value
## (Intercept)  251.580      7.330   34.32
## Days          10.378      1.479    7.02
```

By the way, it's not generally recommended to use random effects when the grouping variables have a very small number (e.g. <5 or 6) levels: see [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#zero-variance) ...

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand the mechanic here. The calculated variances for the *random effects* in your example are `c(703.38, 35.34)`. What I would like to do is to fix these values to let's say `c(700, 30)` so only the fixed effects are estimated.

Comment: Works fine, `environment(dd)$pp$beta(1)` gives me the new estimates. Is it possible to also have access to the standard errors on these estimates?

Comment: yes: construct the new model as shown in the last three code lines in my answer, then do (e.g. `coef(summary(m1X))`

Comment: Using `optim(fn=objfun,par=s0, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0)` in the 3rd last line might be useful because `theta` should not allowed to be < 0. I had an application where this was necessary, otherwise there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

For larger data sets it might be worth noting that the optimization step in [Ben Bolkers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732683) can be simplified to a one dimensional optimization problem. The final `theta` will always be a scaler of `c(700, 30)`.

Especially if there are more scalar/intercept-only random effects it is worth changing the `objfun` in the following way:

```
objfun <- function(x,target=c(700,30)) {
  scaled_theta <- s0*x
  mm <- buildMM(scaled_theta)
  return(sum((unlist(VarCorr(mm))-target)^2))
}
s0 <- sqrt(c(700,30)/sigma(m1)^2)
opt <- optim(fn=objfun,par=1, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = 0)
```