# Running a linear mixed model (lmer, lme4) with pre-defined variance components in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, variance

I am creating a linear mixed model for which I did estimate/define my variance components in advance. Now I would like to add them to the function but I dont know how to do this. The currently used "lmer"-function from the "lme4"-package does estimate the variance components by itself and I dont know how to pre-define them.

Thanks in advance!

```
For Example this data:

library(lme4)

f <- rnorm(10, mean=1.4025, sd=0.101)
m <- rnorm(10, mean=1.9025, sd=0.15)
gain <-  c(f,m,f,m)
s <- c("f","f","f","f","f","m","m","m","m","m")
sex <- c(s,s,s,s)
i <- c(1:10)
anim <- as.factor(c(i,i,i,i))

invented <- data.frame(gain,sex,anim)

# model

lmm <- lmer(gain ~ sex + (1|anim), data = d)
summary(lmm)

# How can I add variance components to the model?
# Fixed-effect-variance = 0.0135
# Random-effect-variance = 0.0045
```

Comment: You cannot fit a model with a pre-defined residual variance.

Comment: Youre right (I edidted the post). I want to predefine the variance of the fixed and random effects.

Comment: That can still not be right. I would somewhat understand fixing the random effects variance.

Comment: There are people (e.g. animal breeders) who do a variance component analysis and then use those once estimated variance-components to run theyr mixed model (e.g. breeding value estimation). Thats what I would like to do in R but I dont see a way to tell the function my desired variance-components.

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718754/fixing-variance-values-in-lme4) seems related.